# C# nullable check verify that property is not null

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I have a complex object I want to check is valid. I have a method to check it, but C# nullability checks don't know about them:

```cs
#nullable enable
...

bool IsValid(Thing? thing) 
{
    return thing?.foo != null && thing?.bar != null;
}

...

if(IsValid(thing)) 
{
   thing.foo.subProperty; // CS8602 warning: foo is possibly null here
```

Is there any way to apply something like TypeScript's type-gates here? If `IsValid` is true then we *know* that `thing.foo` is not null, but the C# analyser can't see inside the function. If I inline the check it can, but then I'm copy-pasting code and this is a simple example.

Is there any annotation or pattern where I can have the nullability analysis with the more complex checks?

Comment: From .NET 5 onwards you can use `MemberNotNullWhen`, but that will only work if `IsValid` is made a method of `Thing`.

Comment: Have opened a C# language discussion about allowing MemberNotNullWhen in more places: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4563

Comment: Ah, that's frustrating, as I want to validate that both `thing` is not null and `thing.property` is not null when it passes the validity check, it looks like I can do one or the other but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) like this:

```
if (IsValid(thing))
{
    thing.foo!.subProperty;
}
```

As @JeroenMostert points out, while it won't help you with `foo`, an alternative is the [`NotNullWhen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullwhenattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute.

The compiler knows `thing` is not `null` here, but `foo` might still be `null`.

```
bool IsValid([NotNullWhen(true)] Thing? thing)
{
    return thing?.foo != null && thing?.bar != null;
}

if (IsValid(thing))
{
    thing.foo;
}
```

Comment: `NotNullWhen` will not do the trick because it can only establish that `thing` is not `null`. It will not establish that `thing.foo` is not `null`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are correct, thank you. I have edited the answer.